# Insert values in DB table when Wordpress post is submitted?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created custom tables in the database along with the standard Wordpress tables and I want to insert values in these tables when post is submitted.

For clarification: When submitting post it's creating records in Wordpress tables right? so I want to insert some other values in another table parallely with this.

Do you know any method to do above mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to declare `global $wpdb` which will help to interact with the wordpress tables

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."name of your custom table";
```

The insert query in wordpress:-

```
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
               'column name' => 'values' 
                )
        );
```